# Pandas get average from second dataframe of the last N rows within time interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have 2 DFs:

DF1

| Name | Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 10:00:00 | 1. |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 11:00:00 | 1.5 |
| object 2 | 2021-11-01 10:30:00 | 1.7 |

DF2

| Name | Timestamp | feature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 8:00:00 | 0.9 |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 9:00:00 | 1.1 |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 9:30:00 | 1.3 |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 12:00:00 | 1. |
| object 2 | 2021-11-01 10:00:00 | 1.3 |
| object 2 | 2021-11-01 11:30:00 | 1.9 |

Per row from DF1, I would like to get the rolling average of the last N rows from DF2 that have the same `Name` and the `Timestamp` is smaller than the row I am considering. (Say N=2 in this example)

Example output should look like:

| Name | Timestamp | Value | AVG of feature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 10:00:00 | 1. | (1.1 + 1.3)/2 |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 11:00:00 | 1.5 | (1.1 + 1.3)/2 |
| object 2 | 2021-11-01 10:30:00 | 1.7 | 1.3 |

Ideally I would be able to do even weighted averages depending on time differences. For example

| Name | Timestamp | Value | AVG of feature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 10:00:00 | 1. | (60min * 1.1 + 30min * 1.3)/(2 * 90min) |
| object 1 | 2021-11-01 11:00:00 | 1.5 | (120min * 1.1 + 90min * 1.3)/(2 * 210min) |
| object 2 | 2021-11-01 10:30:00 | 1.7 | 1.3 |

IMPORTANT: My issue is that doing an `DF1.apply` is taking really long as I have big dataframes (DF1 is around twice as big as DF2). I believe the most important bottleneck is on how to find the biggest timestamp in DF2 that is smaller than the current row in DF1

Comment: why do you have a value for object1 11:00? do you want to include all timestamps before or only those between 10:00 and 11:00?

Comment: So I want to include the previous N records, say N=2. Then, for object 1 11:00, I would like to include the previous 2 records, no matter when they happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to align the timestamps:

```
df1.join(pd
  .merge_asof(df2.sort_values(by='Timestamp'),
              df1.sort_values(by='Timestamp')
                 .reset_index()
                 .drop(columns='Value')
                 .rename(columns={'Timestamp': 'TS'}),
              by='Name', left_on='Timestamp', right_on='TS',
              direction='forward')
  .assign(weight=lambda d: d['TS'].sub(d['Timestamp']).dt.total_seconds(),
          feature=lambda d: d['feature'].mul(d['weight'])
         )
  .groupby('index').apply(lambda g: g['feature'].sum()/g['weight'].sum()/len(g))
  .rename('AVG of (feature)')
)
```

output:

```
         Name           Timestamp  Value  AVG of (feature)
0.0  object 1 2021-11-01 10:00:00    1.0          0.583333
1.0  object 1 2021-11-01 11:00:00    1.5               NaN
2.0  object 2 2021-11-01 10:30:00    1.7          1.300000
```

*NB. if you want to propagate the previous value of the AVG you can use `ffill` per group*

Comment: This seems really useful! However, I think this would use all records from DF2 that has the same `Name`? However, I would like this to be a parameter? Say I want to only use the last 3 timestamps, but no more?